# Подгрузка содержимого или как сделать селектор стран и городов?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

Подгрузка содержимого или как сделать селектор стран и городов c выводом содержимого файла каждого города?
В песочнице выложил свой код. 
И сделал небольшое видео, что мне нужно. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSxKDltA9-E`
И так сейчас на сайте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую открывается и появляется без перезагрузки содержимое. Мне нужно на сайте организовать тоже самое, но алгоритм другой. Чтобы прийти к окончательному результату сначала выбираем Страну, затем город в этой стране, после выбора города появляется содержимое файла город.php Таких файлов подразумевается множество.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   var show_content = "Показать";
   var clear_content = "Скрыть";
   var wait_content = "<img src='https://aviareysi.ru/loading.gif'><b style='color:#337ab7;'>Подождите, идет загрузка...</b>";
   
  $("#form_1 input").on("click", function(event){
   if ($(this).val() == show_content) {
    $('#content1').html(wait_content);
    $('#form_1').ajaxForm(function(response) { 
    $('#form_1 input').val(clear_content);
                $('#content1').html(response); 
     });
   } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(show_content);
    $('#content1').html('');     
    }           
  });      
   });
```

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .header-logo{text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;}
     .features-nav{display:none!important;}
.featured-in {
    background-color: #f7f8f9;
    overflow-x: hidden;}
    table {
      border: 0;
    }

    table thead {
      display: none;
    }

    table tr {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    }

    table td {
      display: block;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    }

    table td:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    table td:before {
      content: attr(data-label);
      float: left;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
      .header-logo{text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;}
.features-nav{display:none!important;}
.featured-in {
    background-color: #f7f8f9;
    overflow-x: hidden;}
    table {
      border: 0;
    }

    table thead {
      display: none;
    }

    table tr {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    }

    table td {
      display: block;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    }

    table td:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    table td:before {
      content: attr(data-label);
      float: left;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .poisk{font-family: Open Sans;
font-weight: 400;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 2.5rem;
background: #e5f4fe;}
.poiski{margin: 10px;
background: #88ceed;
width: 300px;
display: block;
color: #fff;
font-size: 2.5rem;
height: 30px;text-align: center;
float: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 10px auto !important;}
  }
 .div_form {
width:150px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
input[type='submit'] {
display: inline-block;

}
.table {
margin: 0 auto
}
.table-responsive {
background: #ffffff;}
.btn,.btn1,.btn2,.btn3,.btn4,.btn-info:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #31b0d5;
  border-color: #269abc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 1px !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://aviareysi.ru/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<link href="https://aviareysi.ru/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://aviareysi.ru/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" style="padding:0px; margin:0 auto;text-align:center">
      <h3>Все авиабилеты<br>из Москвы в Санкт-Петербург</h3>
   
<div class="div_form">
 <form method="post" action="https://aviareysi.ru/peterburg.php" name="form1" id="form_1" >
 <input  type="submit" value="Показать" class="btn btn-info">
 </form>
 </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
       <div class="demo" >
       <div class="table-responsive" id="content1"> 
    
      </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Завтра вами приведенные ссылки могут быть неактуальными.А ответ мог бы помочь другим у кого возникли бы подобные потребности.Так что приводите ваши примеры тут,и пишите в чем проблема

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan добавил, но почему-то здесь при нажатии кнопки не открылось окно, а на Codepen открывается.

Comment: $('#form_1').on('submit', function(e)
 {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url: $(this).attr('action'),
   success: function(response)
   {
    $("#content1").html(response);
    console.log(response);
   }
  });
 });

Comment: чтоб обойти кросс доменные запросы можете у вас на сервере создать какой нибудь test.php файл со следующим кодом `<?php
 echo file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
?>`, а в самом js сделать запрос уже к нему передавая ссылку чтоб уже PHP вернул вам контент на этой странице.Вот так  

 `$('#form_2').on('submit', function(e)
 {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url: 'test.php',
   method: "POST",
   data: "url=" + $(this).attr('action'),

   success: function(response)
   {
    $("#content1").html(response);
    console.log(response);
   }
  });
 });`

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/7uHhC это результат который я получил в ходе действий .
Если все так как вы хотели то сообщите мне чтоб опубликовать все это как ответ .Спасибо

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan Если выбор города и страны, то выкладывайте, если просто при нажатии кнопки то это у меня и так работало, вот тут https://aviareysi.ru видно